# Form elements are not moving to the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to web programming.

I have a style tag inside my `head` tag like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .center {
      float: none;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
  }
```

And I use twitter bootstrap. I have my `form` wrapped inside the `div` block

```
<div class="center"
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Legend</legend>
        <label>Label name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
        <span class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</span>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

But the `form` elements not even moved to center.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: try this:

.center {
text-align: center;
}

or replace div tag by <center>...</center>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is centered but since div is block element you are unable to find out the difference unless you give some width (**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dLDgK/1/)** with specified width)

So try this

```
 .center {
      float: none;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center
  }
legend{
    text-align:left
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dLDgK/)**

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
.center {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text-align:center to the container div..

```
  .center {
      float: none;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      text-align:center;
  }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xhjHS/

Answer (score 0):

use center tag before form tag.

```
<center>
 <form></from>
 </center>
```